# editText.setId(R.id.myid);

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Пытался использовать, не заработало. Можете, пожалуйста, рассказать как вообще использовать такую конструкцию?

Comment: для чего вообще это использовать? В Вашем случае?

Comment: Аргументом должно быть целое число типа int. При этом, если он совпадет с числом из класса R, то у вас будут проблемы. Класс R генрируется автоматически и вы не можете что то там писать. Зачем нужно самому переприсваивать ID?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "не заработало"?

Answer (score 2):

Согласно документации

> Sets the identifier for this view. The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive number.

То есть можно установить любое положительное целое число в качестве id и уникальность его не требуется.

В вашем случае получается что вы пытаетесь ассоциировать editText c id, который уже есть в классе R и есть View у которого установлен этот id.
Значит когда вы вызовете findViewById() вам вернется тот view, который был первым найден в текущей иерархии view-элементов, и не факт что это будет нужный вам editText. Чтобы избежать этого надо у view который был ассоциирован с myid до editText изменить id на другой

Начиная с API 17 можно использовать метод

> public static int generateViewId ()
>
> Generate a value suitable for use in setId(int). This value will not
>   collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id.

Answer (score 0):

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myId)
```

Находим элемент по **ID**.

Думаю, `setId()` нужен для присваивания элементу **ID**

Comment: Ну да, я хочу переприсвоить id.